# Mac Link .h file to .cpp files

Tags: c++, macos

I'm a student and have just been introduced to modularity in cpp. I don't understand my mistake though.

I have 3 files.

One `test.cpp`

```cpp
/**\
  * @file   testFile.cpp
  * @author TomPlanche
  * @brief  test file links
\**/

// . Importation Des Bibliothèques Nécessaires.
#include <iostream>
#include "fraction.h"


int main(void) {
    /**\
      * @goal                           :  test file links
      * @author :                       :  T.Planche
      * @remarks                        :  non
    \**/

    // ! Déclaration Variables
    Fraction frac1 = {1, 2};

    cout << frac1.denominateur << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

One `fraction.cpp`

```cpp
/**\
  * @file   fraction.cpp
  * @author TomPlanche
  * @brief  Exercice TD2 R1.01/PT2
\**/

// ! Importation Des Bibliothèques Nécessaires.
#include "fraction.h"


// ! Définition Sous-Programmes
int pgcd(int nb1, int nb2) {
    int min = (nb1 < nb2) ? nb1 : nb2;

    for (int i = min; i <= min; i--) {
        if ((nb1 % i == 0) && (nb2 % i == 0)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}


Fraction simplifier(const Fraction fraction) {
    /**\
      * @goal                           :  simplifier une fraction
      * @author :                       :  T.Planche
      * @remarks                        :  aucune
    \**/
    
    Fraction fractionFinale;
    int pgdcFraction;

    pgdcFraction = pgcd(fraction.numerateur, fraction.denominateur);
    
    fractionFinale.numerateur = fraction.numerateur / pgdcFraction;
    fractionFinale.denominateur = fraction.denominateur / pgdcFraction;

    return fractionFinale;
}


Fraction addition(Fraction frac1, Fraction frac2) {
    Fraction fractionResultat;

    if (frac1.denominateur == frac2.denominateur) {
        fractionResultat.denominateur = frac1.denominateur;
        fractionResultat.numerateur = frac1.numerateur + frac2.numerateur;
    } else {
        fractionResultat.denominateur = frac1.denominateur*frac2.denominateur;
        fractionResultat.numerateur = frac1.numerateur*frac2.denominateur + frac2.numerateur*frac1.denominateur;
    }

    return fractionResultat;
}

void afficherFraction(const Fraction fraction) {
    Fraction fractionSimplifiee = simplifier(fraction);

    cout << fractionSimplifiee.numerateur << "/" << fractionSimplifiee.denominateur << endl;
}
```

and one `fraction.h`

```cpp
#ifndef FRACTION_H
#define FRACTION_H

#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

struct Fraction {
    int numerateur; // Le signe est porté sur ce nombre
    unsigned int denominateur; // > 0
};

int pgcd(int nb1, int nb2);
//! @goal : Retourne Le Pdcg De Deux Entiers

Fraction simplifier(Fraction fraction);
//! @goal : Simplifier Une Fraction

Fraction addition(Fraction frac1, Fraction frac2);
//! @goal : Additionner Deux Fractions

Fraction soustraction(Fraction frac1, Fraction frac2);
//! @goal : Soustraire Deux Fractions

Fraction multiplication(Fraction frac1, Fraction frac2);
//! @goal : Multiplier Deux Fractions

Fraction division(Fraction frac1, Fraction frac2);
//! @goal : Diviser Deux Fractions

void afficherFraction(const Fraction fraction);
//! @goal : Afficher Une Fraction


#endif
```

When I try to add just a `Fraction frac1 = {1, 2};` it compiles.
But when I try to `afficherFraction` I have

```
cd "/Users/tom_planche_mbpm1/Desktop/BUT/R1.01-IntroDev/PT2/TD2/" && g++ testFile.cpp -o testFile && "/Users/tom_planche_mbpm1/Desktop/BUT/R1.01-IntroDev/PT2/TD2/"testFile
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "simplifier(Fraction)", referenced from:
      _main in testFile-8df18c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm on a MacBook Pro M1 on macOS Monterey (21C5031d)

Thanks !

Comment: You most likely forgot to compile and link the second .cpp file. Show the command you used to build the program

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the *full* and *complete* build output.

Comment: Note that .h files *aren't* linked to .cpp files. The linker links all your compiled cpp files together, doesn't know about the .h files, and it will look for things to be defined in *any cpp file in the project*.

Comment: Also, considering that you have *two* `main` functions in the code you show, the error seems somewhat odd. It seems you don't build with any of the shown source files.

Comment: On another (but unrelated) note: In your header files, you should only include other header files that are actually *needed*. The `fraction.h` header file doesn't need the `<iostream>` header file, or any of the symbols defined or declared in it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude just did it :/

Comment: So you are only compiling `testFile.cpp` (which I'm going to guess is what is marked as `test.cpp` in the question), not `fraction.cpp` - you need to compile both files and link them together

Comment: FYI, you shouldn't put `using` statements like `using std::cout` at the top level of a header file. Putting them in a .cpp file or inside a function is fine, but not where you have them. See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141317/use-using-in-c-or-avoid-it.

Comment: simpifier(const Fraction) does not implement simplifier(Fraction)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You build your executable with:

```
g++ testFile.cpp -o testFile
```

but you're forgetting the second source file. You can either do everything in one line:

```
g++ testFile.cpp fraction.cpp -o testFile
```

but with an eye on the future, when your program may become much larger, it's a better idea to use separate compilation:

```
g++ -c testFile.cpp 
g++ -c fraction.cpp
g++ testFile.o fraction.o -o testFile
```

When you start using a build system (Make, Cmake) this is the way it will be done: compile only whatever file needs recompiling, and then link them together.

Btw, it's a good idea to add a couple of compiler flags, such as `-g -O2`. The first one makes debugging possible in gdb and such, the second one says "make optimized code".

Comment: thank you !
I ran the `testFile.cpp` and vscode didn't add the other file to the compilation...
Do you know how I can automatically compile both while asking to run `test.cpp` ?

Comment: You need to read some tutorial. You can not "run" a `.cpp` file. And I don't use vscode, so I don't know about automatic compiling.